# ... external page load with jQuery... + then run a function

Tags: jquery, function, load

... I have this simple piece of jQuery code that loads in an external page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#info a').click(function(){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#info_show').load(href).fadeToggle();

        return false;

    });
});
```

After loading the page I wanted to run a function that centers this content into the window...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#info').click(function(){

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#info_show').load(href).fadeToggle();

        return false;

        function move_div(){

            window_width = $(window).width();
            window_height = $(window).height();

            obj_width = $('#holder').width();
            obj_height = $('#holder').height();

            $('#holder').css('top', (window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (window_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));

        }

        $(window).resize(function(){

            move_div();

        });

    });

});
```

... the 'move_div' does not run... can anyone help solve this... ?

T

Comment: For starters, move the return false statement down to the bottom of your click function.

Comment: all of that `move_div` stuff is inside your `$('#info').click(function(){`. so, if you click on your element identified by `#info`, you'll see it run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .load function takes a callback parameter that will be called:

> ... after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. \

see: [.load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Updated code that moves the return and adds `move_div` as the load completion callback:

```
$('#info').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    function move_div(){

        window_width = $(window).width();
        window_height = $(window).height();

        obj_width = $('#holder').width();
        obj_height = $('#holder').height();

        $('#holder').css('top', (window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (window_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        move_div();
    });

    // Add move_div as the load complete callback
    $('#info_show').load(href, move_div).fadeToggle();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement before the declaration of the function. So it is probable that the move_div() function never gets executed.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#info').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#info_show').load(href).fadeToggle();

        function move_div(){
            window_width = $(window).width();
            window_height = $(window).height();
            obj_width = $('#holder').width();
            obj_height = $('#holder').height();
            $('#holder').css('top', (window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (window_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));

        }
        $(window).resize(function(){
            move_div();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```